# CardView is not Collapsing in scrolling activity

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have Scrolling activity and I have a CardView in it which behave like this floating action button as shown in this animation.

[image: FAB hides but CardView doesn't]

As you can see fab is fading (in and out), but the card view is not behaving like that.
 
My layout.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.rhcloud.arshadali.task.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/id_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:foreground="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_googleplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_apk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="com.javiersantos"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Any reason of -1?

Comment: I think the guy who -1 it is fool and din't get you!

Comment: So can you be the guy who answers it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Card View should be a child of your collapsing toolbar for the effects to take place (Place it above the Toolbar).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.rhcloud.arshadali.task.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/id_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:foreground="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_googleplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_apk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="com.javiersantos"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put CardView inside a LinearLayout and move it to the top of Toolbar.
It works.

Like this:

```
       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Overlay.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer is too late, but you can try this simplest way. Put the card view in the "Content Activity" which is usually automatically generated when you choose Scrolling Activity template in android studio. Remember, if you want to have multiple card view, you should put those card views under one Linear/Relative Layout in the Content Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This work:
if you are using Databinding this is the perfect solution:

In same Class:

```
@BindingAdapter("hideWithAppBarLayout")
    public static void hideWithAppBarLayout(View view, AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {

        if (appBarLayout == null) return;

        if (view.getParent() instanceof CoordinatorLayout) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

            lp.setAnchorId(appBarLayout.getId());

            appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener((AppBarLayout.BaseOnOffsetChangedListener) (appBar, verticalOffset) -> {
                float percentage = ((float) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / appBar.getTotalScrollRange());
                //on collapsing
                if (percentage == 1) view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //on expending
                if (percentage == 0) view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            });
        }
    }
```

In xml layout do this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:hideWithAppBarLayout="@{appbar}"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    //todo    

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```